# Set view element BindingContext - mvvm cross

Tags: mvvmcross

Is it possible to set element data context in MvvmCross?
Suppose I have:

```
<RelativeLayout>
     <TextView/> <TextView/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and I'd like to set RelativeLayout data context to viewmodel property.

XAML equivalent of:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding someProperty}">
 <TextBlock/> <TextBlock/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't currently do this directly in a single axml file in MvvmCross at present.

However:

1. You can use `MvxFrameControl` to load a sub-axml file (a bit like an `include`) and then set the `DataContext` for everything inside that sub-view
2. MvvmCross is open source - so you can extend and adapt it...